# JavaScript Get image from file as Base64

Tags: javascript, image, base64

If I have a file which contains an image in Base64 text, how can I load it as an image in JavaScript?

Currently I'm using `fetch` to get the file and then insert it's content as the image `src` attribute.
I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Does it work the way you did it?

Comment: @Costa Yes, it does work the way I did.